# React component being remounted whenever it's changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React, and as practice tried creating a simple todo list app. To my understanding, (in a simple application like mine) a component should only be getting mounted once, and thus it's constructor also should only be called once. **I used the Create-React-App generator to get started.**

The app consists of the following components:

An `ItemForm` that allows the user to enter their next todo item.

```
class ItemForm extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {value: '',
                clickReciever: props.clickReciever};
  
  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}

handleChange(event){
  this.setState({
    value: event.target.value
  });
}

handleSubmit(event){
  {this.state.clickReciever(this.state.value)}
}

render() {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>``
      <label>
        Name:
        <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
      </label>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

}

And a `TodoList` that will show all the user's entered Todo items

```
export class TodoList extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state={
    list: [],
  };

//Don't forget to do this for every function you write (besides the constructor and render)
this.clickReciever = this.clickReciever.bind(this);
}

clickReciever(value){
  const newList = this.state.list.slice();
  newList.push(value);

  this.setState({list: newList});
}

render(){
  let listItems = this.state.list.map((item, index) =>
    <li key={index}>{item}</li>
  );
  return (
  <div className="TodoList">
      <ul>{listItems}</ul>
      <ItemForm clickReciever={(value) => this.clickReciever(value)}/>
  </div> 
  );
}
```

}

Here is my `index.js` file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { TodoList } from './components/TodoList';
import './index.css';

import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <TodoList/>,
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

The `TodoList` consists of an `ItemForm` component. When the `TodoList` is created it creates an `ItemForm`, passing the `clickReciever` function of `TodoList` as a prop to the new `ItemForm`. When submit in `ItemForm` is clicked, it then calls the `clickReciever` function that was passed to it, allowing the `TodoList` state to be updated with the new todo item.

The problem I'm running into is that every time the "Submit" button is clicked, `ReactDOM.render` in index.js is being called, causing the `TodoList` component being passed to it to be remounted. This results in the `TodoList` constructor being called, and the `list` state of the `TodoList` to be reset.

The overall effect is that when submit is clicked, the new item shows up for a split second (which tells me that `clickReciever` is working properly), and disappears.

I'm not sure if this is a result of me implementing the components wrong, or if I'm misunderstanding how a React app is structured. Also please feel free to provide feedback on any aspects of my code, this is my first time dabbling with React or any type of web development, so any feedback is appreciated!

Comment: It looks like your `onChange` function is getting called a bit too many times, You may want to limit that: `onChange={() => this.handleChange()}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to how the `form` element behaves, usually when it is submitted the page is reloaded. In your case, you'll want to stop this from happening by doing this:

```js
// ItemForm

handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // <-- Add this
  this.state.clickReciever(this.state.value)
}
```

Comment: This fixed it, thanks!